# After changes in pam crontab stop working

Tags: linux, unix, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have made changes in :
cat /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive

sudo vi /etc/pam.d/cron

sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf

after rebooting system crontab stop working when I check syslog it shows below error:

PAM (cron) illegal module type: ession
 cron[4936]: Permission denied

Comment: Yes, I found some file, where I have made the spelling mistake.